# Using a global collection to save Boost shared_ptr:s for pre-built octree data, for fast point cloud raycast operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, point-cloud-library

I am making some test to create a raycasting system for virtual reality point cloud viewer. The base is made with Unity Engine but importing, reading from the disk and rendering the point cloud data is independent as dll plugins for Unity and GPU shader code.

The point cloud data is divided to independent blocks, which are dynamically loaded and unloaded when user moves in the virtual reality scene. I made the first tests by creating a global std::unordered_map where the key is the name of the data file for the loaded block, and value is the Boost shared_ptr. I'll paste the code below, it should be easy to understand.

The code below works perfectly with one data block, but with more blocks it seems to do that I get the index of a point hitted, and then checking the point values by reading the cloud data itself by the index, this actually uses the correct result index with a random block data. When I sweep with the VR controller laser pointer I see my visual advice in the scene going on the area of an other block's area, then jumping to the area of another block, and so on. This is probably a threading issue because findInOcTree is called from Unity main thread but createOcTree and releaseOcTree are called from a thread made for asynchronous disk reads. But I'm not sure at all if using a global collection for shared_ptr:s this way is problem-free.

So, all ideas to which direction I should go are welcome. Is there a better concurrent collection option to be used instead of std::unordered_map or should I just use some kind of manual locking technique? Are there any other dangers which I can't spot right now?

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)

#include <vector>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/octree/octree.h>


// Link following functions C-style (required for plugins)
extern "C"
{   
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);

    /// Two different ways to say the same thing
    std::unordered_map<std::string, pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr> ocTreeMap;
    //std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>>> ocTreeMap;

    // using this makes no difference with many blocks; one block works with and without
    std::unordered_map<string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr> cloudMap;

    EXPORT_API bool createOcTree(char *blockName)
    {
        if (ocTreeMap.find(blockName) == ocTreeMap.end())
        {
            pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr octree(new pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>(0.0025f));

            octree->setInputCloud(cloud);
            octree->addPointsFromInputCloud();

            /// using this makes no difference with many blocks; one block works with and without
            if (cloudMap.find(blockName) != cloudMap.end())
            {
                cloudMap.erase(blockName);
            }
            cloudMap[blockName] = cloud;
            ocTreeMap[blockName] = octree;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    EXPORT_API bool releaseOcTree(char *blockName)
    {
        if (ocTreeMap.erase(blockName) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            /// using this makes no difference with many blocks; one block works with and without
            cloudMap.erase(blockName);  

            return true;
        }
    }


    EXPORT_API bool findInOcTree(char *filePath, float originX, float originY, float originZ, float directionX, float directionY, float directionZ, float* hitX, float* hitY, float* hitZ)
    {
        Eigen::Vector3f origin(originX, originY, originZ);
        Eigen::Vector3f direction(directionX, directionY, directionZ);
        std::vector<int> k_indices;

        boost::shared_ptr<pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>> octree = ocTreeMap[filePath];

        /// using this makes no difference with many blocks; one block works with and without
        boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>> pCloud = cloudMap[filePath];

        octree->getIntersectedVoxelIndices(origin, direction, k_indices, 1);

        if (!k_indices.empty())
        {
            *hitX = pCloud->points[k_indices[0]].x;
            *hitY = pCloud->points[k_indices[0]].y;
            *hitZ = pCloud->points[k_indices[0]].z;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a multithreading issue, but is not clear what exactly the problem is. Too much meta information (VR, controller...), which is distracting and does not help understanding the actual problem. So if you cannot minimize your example, please be more specific about your multithreading issue.


unordered_map is not thread safe in any way. You have data races everywhere. boost offers containers with concurrency support. Using them would be the first step.

Comment: Adding on to what lars wrote: After reading your first paragraph, my initial reaction was that there is no way this question is going somewhere productive. Too much focus on high-level context, not enough attention to what the actual problem is *(remember: this is based on just the first paragraph)*. No attempt to abstract the issue away from its context. Context is good, but it's usually better as an ending explanation, not as the question lead-in. Maybe reverse the order of your explanation's flow? See also [ask].